# Gauss map of a product

Tags: differential-geometry

It is probably a stupic question, but does anybody know if the degree of the gauss map of the cartesian product of two manifolds is the product of the degrees of the gauss maps of each of them?

Thank you,

Yoann

Comment: What do you mean by the Gauss map of a manifold?

Comment: Please be very explicit about where these manifolds are living.

Comment: Ok I wiil be more precise! In the real plane R^2, I study the closed connected component of an hyperplane arrangements. Hence these chambers are "polygons" in the plane, which are bounded by a finite chain of straight line segments. I consider a normal vector field U on each segment (the direction is outward or inward depending on other assumptions). If I can decompose the boundary B as the product of 2 segments B_1 X B_2, is it true that the degree of the Gauss map: U/|U|  from B to S^1, is the product of the degrees of the gauss map from B_1 to S^1 and  from B_2 to S^2 ? Thank you!

Comment: From B_2 to the sphere S^1 of course, sorry